# MySQL database for push notifications one user with multiple devices

Tags: mysql, database, push-notification, token

I have a database to save registration ID's from a mobile application after a user is logged in that is working correctly. I have a web form that allows me to select users in the database and send them a push message.

My question is, how do I account for users with multiple devices? I want the user to be able to have multiple registration ID's in the user table so I can send a message to all devices related to that user.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using a selfwritten system? One solution would be to create a new table only with registration IDs coupled with a user ID. Therefore you could adress every single device of one user.

Comment: Yes, it is a self written system, and I've actually considered this approach before. My only issue is that the registration ID's tend to expire if they are not used or the app is deleted, so I would need a table that is endlessly long. For example, if one user has deleted the app or not used it in a while, their reg ID would change. If that user has 5 reg IDs in the database, then only one or two of them might be relevant while the others are depreciated. I could run an update query, but I wouldn't know which reg ID's are active or which to update. That was a very good suggestion though!!

Comment: Maybe a timestamp column is the way to go. is it possible for you to update the ID specific timestamp?

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to update the reg ID on command. Is that what you are asking?